# Maven Build Cache skipped when additional goals are passed

Tags: maven

I'm setting up Maven Build Cache for my multimodule project.
I'm also using the default cache configuration.
When I rerun `mvn test`, after initial cache seeding with `mvn install`, it works like a charm, but when I'm passing something like `mvn test jacoco:report` it runs tests again... Why?

maven-build-cache-config.xml ->

```
    <configuration>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <hashAlgorithm>SHA-256</hashAlgorithm>
        <validateXml>true</validateXml>
        <remote enabled="true" id="gitlab-maven">
            <url>...</url>
        </remote>
        <local>
            <maxBuildsCached>3</maxBuildsCached>
        </local>
        <projectVersioning adjustMetaInf="true"/>
    </configuration>
    
    <input>
        <global>
            <!-- If not defined, default glob is "*" -->
            <glob>
                {*.java,*.yaml,*.xml,*.properties,*.json}
            </glob>
            <includes>
                <!-- By default, project sources and resources directories are included (src/main/java and src/main/resources) -->
                <!-- In this example, the goal is to include a widder range of src directories (like src/main/assembly or src/main/groovy) -->
                <!--                <include>src/</include>-->
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <!---->
                <exclude>pom.xml</exclude>
                <exclude>**/target</exclude>
                <exclude>target</exclude>
                <exclude>../target</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </global>
    </input>
    <executionControl>
        <runAlways>
            <goalsLists>
                <goalsList artifactId="maven-install-plugin">
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install</goal>
                    </goals>
                </goalsList>
            </goalsLists>
        </runAlways>
    </executionControl>
```

I'm expecting that the cache will be restored and tests will be skipped.